# setup and write demo test the robolectric in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, robolectric

Do anyone know how to integrate robolectric into android studio?
How to write sample test?
How to launch it?

I am working with android studio not to long, and I am too bad with gradle.
Searching the net didn't give me a result - I even could not launch official demo - https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-samples . My android studio do not saw the test class.

Please give me simpliest step by step gide, thanks

Comment: What i found - only one sample robolectric app runs without any "magic" with gradle, its - https://github.com/blundell/tests-app-robolectric-junit
And an article about it - http://blog.blundell-apps.com/android-gradle-app-with-robolectric-junit-tests/
Maybe this will save some hours for others

Answer (score 1):

Since robolectric runs in a JVM (i.e. not on a device or emulator), it is just a library and adding the test runner is all that's needed.

Make sure that the android SDK is later in the classpath than robolectric or junit - otherwise you'll get the stubbed methods from the android SDK.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyActivityTest {

@Test
public void shouldHaveApplicationName() throws Exception {
    String appName = new MyActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
    assertThat(appName, equalTo("MyActivity"));
}
```

}

See http://robolectric.org/quick-start/

Comment: Actually I have done it already. And your answeir does not provide step by step instruvtions for Android Studio. 
1 Instruction appeares simple: clone sample proj  github.com/blundell/tests-app-robolectric-junit 
2 Copy robolectir submodule into you app
3 add it as  module dependency 
4 compile with "gradle test" command

Comment: @AntonKizema you can answer your own question